# How to Know if JFileChooser is null and if its null dont Update the database

Tags: java, netbeans, jfilechooser

This is my code

```
    private void UploadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    JFileChooser Attach = new JFileChooser();
    try {
        if (Attach.showOpenDialog(Upload) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File ImageFile = Attach.getSelectedFile();
            lbl_Image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageFile.toString()));
            lbl_Image.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

            filename = ImageFile.getAbsolutePath();

            try {
                File Image = new File(filename);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Image);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                    bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
                }
                person_image = bos.toByteArray();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then this my code for Updating the database

```
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(Module.url, Module.username, Module.password);
                String sql = "Update resume set Image = ?, FirstName = ? where ID = '" + ID.getText() + "'";
                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setBytes(1, person_image);
                ps.setString(2, WordUtils.capitalizeFully(Fname.getText()));
                ps.executeUpdate();
```

I want to know, how can i make the program if the user want to update the data in the database and he didn't choose any file on the JFileChooser the Image(Blob) Field in the database should not be updated.

because on my codes if the user is not choose any file on the JFileChooser the Image(Blob) field is updating to NULL.

Comment: simply check for `Null` before executing update query !!

Comment: can you give me a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your person_image array for null like this

```
if (person_image != null) {
  // Now do whatever you want to do !!
}
else{
  throw new ImageNotSelectedCustomException(); // this is your custom exception
  // you can also simply ignore it and do another piece of work
}
```

**Note :** Please read some [basic tutorial on Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/) , since **checking for Null is not a big deal**  , if you can write this much of code yourself.

Comment: Sorry i can't vote up your answer because im new here..
and im new in Java Programming.
Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem , but i strongly suggest please go through the  **tutorial** if you want to learn something , otherwise you'll end up in these troubles more often !!